# Issue writing XML using erlsom

Tags: xml, xsd, erlang

I am busy with a project in Erlang using a lot of XML and are trying to learn how to write XML in Erlang using erlsom. I'm pulling my hair out now after struggling for about 2 full days, and the more I read now the more confused I'm getting.

The extract of the XSD file (csta.xsd) containing the portion where the code stops working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSPY v5 rel. 4 U (http://www.xmlspy.com) by Thomas Miller (Siemens Enterprise Networks) -->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://www.ecma-international.org/standards/ecma-323/csta/ed3" xmlns:csta="http://www.ecma-international.org/standards/ecma-323/csta/ed3" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" schemaLocation="my_envelope.xsd"/>
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>csta</xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>Capability Exchange Services</xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="get-csta-features.xsd"/>
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="get-logical-device-information.xsd"/>
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="get-physical-device-information.xsd"/>
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="get-switching-function-capabilities.xsd"/>
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="get-switching-function-devices.xsd"/>
  <xsd:include schemaLocation="switching-function-devices.xsd"/>
  <xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>System Services</xsd:documentation>
  </xsd:annotation>
```

In Erlang I am doing the following:

```
XsdFile = "/home/renato/projects/rnlib-erl/rnlib-erl/dmcc/xsd/csta-schemas/csta.xsd".
XsdDir = filename:dirname(XsdFile).
erlsom:compile_xsd_file(XsdFile).
```

Getting error:

```
{error,"Include file not found my_envelope.xsd"}
```

Which I can (somehow) accept, so then I try:

```
erlsom:compile_xsd_file(XsdFile, [{include_dirs, XsdDir}]).
```

Upon which Erlang returns the following error:

```
** exception throw: {'EXIT',{function_clause,[{filename,join,
                                                        [47,"my_envelope.xsd"],
                                                        [{file,"filename.erl"},{line,409}]},
                                              {filename,join,1,[{file,"filename.erl"},{line,396}]},
                                              {erlsom_lib,findFileInDirs,2,
                                                          [{file,"erlsom_lib.erl"},{line,864}]},
                                              {erlsom_lib,findFile,4,[{file,"erlsom_lib.erl"},{line,828}]},
                                              {erlsom_compile,processImports,2,
                                                              [{file,"erlsom_compile.erl"},{line,306}]},
                                              {erlsom_compile,transform,2,
                                                              [{file,"erlsom_compile.erl"},{line,278}]},
                                              {erlsom_compile,compile_parsed_xsd,10,
                                                              [{file,"erlsom_compile.erl"},{line,250}]},
                                              {erlsom,compile_xsd,2,[{file,"erlsom.erl"},{line,142}]}]}}
     in function  erlsom:compile_xsd/2 (erlsom.erl, line 144)
```

`my_envelope.xsd` is in the same directory as `csta.xsd`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`include_dirs` accepts a *list* of strings, not one string, according to the [reference](https://github.com/willemdj/erlsom/blob/9b3f9106a9b1376ab7a4dbdd11cae7bb9835ef0a/doc/reference.md#compile_xsd2).

As the library does not check the types early, you end up with a cryptic error which roughly translates to the fact that `erlsom_lib:findFileInDirs/2` ended up calling `filename:join(47, "my_envelope.xsd")` (probably because the first element of your argument to `include_dirs` was `47`, the ASCII value of `/`).

This should fix your latest error:

```
erlsom:compile_xsd_file(XsdFile, [{include_dirs, [XsdDir]}]).
```

Comment: That was exactly my problem. Thanks.